# Running hyperV inside a windows docker container

Tags: powershell, docker, hyper-v

I have a process which runs primarily with powershell and relies heavily on the hyperV pwsh module to build (at script runtime) and launch a hyper-v instance. This is to programmatically build a windows machine with specific features, updates, and applications, then capture an image of that machine for deployment to physical devices later. 
We want to containerize this process so it can be run more dynamically than on a physical box like it is today.

Critical in this, is we need to be able to build and turn on a hyper-v instance **inside** the container. Currently experimenting on win 1803 with the dockerFile below.

```
# note it doesn't necessarily need to be this image, I just picked it because it was easy
FROM microsoft/powershell:nanoserver-1803 AS powershell
COPY ./mainContainer/ c:/app/
```

and then need pwsh like the lines below to work (primary issue is the lack of the hyperV pwsh module):

```
New-VHD -SizeBytes 100GB -Path $vhdPath
New-VM -Name $VmName -Generation 2 -Path "$TempDirectory\$VmName" -VHDPath $vhdPath -Switch $switchName
Set-VMMemory -VMName $VmName -StartupBytes 4096MB -DynamicMemoryEnabled $false 
Add-VMScsiController -VMName $VmName 
Add-VMDvdDrive -VMName $VmName -ControllerNumber 1 -ControllerLocation 0 -Path $WindowsIsoPath 
Set-VMFirmware -VMName $VmName -FirstBootDevice $dvdDrive 
Start-VM -VMName $VmName 
$vm = Get-Vm $VMName
# then there's little loop waiting for the machine to turn off before continuing
```

I have tried `Install-WindowsFeature` and similar, but always get an error that:
"The term 'Install-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."
I have tried `import-module servermanager`, but that also gives "...not loaded because no valid module file was..."
It seems perhaps the main (current) hurdle may be to get a new module imported in pwsh (within the container) so I can enable the windows feature?

any advice?

update: I found part of the problem was it appears the nanoserver doesn't allow things like dism, so I've updated the dockerFile to:

```
FROM microsoft/powershell:windowsservercore-1803 AS powershell
COPY ./mainContainer/ c:/app/
RUN DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

but now I get an error:

> The source files could not be found.
>   Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

seems I need a different base image, not sure if there is one that can enable hyper-V

Comment: Microsoft says:
>Note: Hyper-V is built into Windows as an optional feature -- there is no Hyper-V download.
So unless you find base image with hyper-v i don't think it is possible to do what you are trying to do.

also docker is the isolated way to use resources of the host operation system but not full virtualization. so not sure that what you are doing is going to bring you any perfomance optimization  comparing to building images directly on you host server.

Comment: perhaps I'll focus on looking for a different base, that's a good thought.
It's not necessarily a drive to get performance gain, it's more about abstracting it away from a dependency on a piece of metal in my cube at the office. I don't care if it takes an extra 25% of time to do the process, really even more is probably fine.